# python: how to bin a list of 3D points efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy

I have a long list of 'points' in 3D, each of which have `[x,y,z,scalar,scalar,...]`

I would like to 'bin' the points in 3D (in x/y/z), or re-organize into a new 'array of arrays' with dimensions [n_bins_x, n_bins_y, n_bins_z], each element of which is a sub-array. I don't need to just 'count' them as with a histogram, but rather would like to end up with an array of points for each bin, packed into a 3D array.

My actual use case involves O(1M) points * O(2K) timesteps, each of which needs to be binned, so high performance is needed.

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import timeit

# ----- generate pts

size_x, size_y, size_z = 5.0, 3.0, 1.0
n_pts = 100000

x = np.random.uniform(0.0, size_x, n_pts )
y = np.random.uniform(0.0, size_y, n_pts )
z = np.random.uniform(0.0, size_z, n_pts )
u = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0,    n_pts )
v = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0,    n_pts )
w = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0,    n_pts )
data = np.vstack((x,y,z,u,v,w)).T

# ----- define bin bounds

n_bins_x, n_bins_y, n_bins_z = 10, 10, 10
n_bins_total = n_bins_x*n_bins_y*n_bins_z
x_bin_bounds = np.linspace(0.0, size_x, n_bins_x+1, dtype=np.float64)
y_bin_bounds = np.linspace(0.0, size_y, n_bins_y+1, dtype=np.float64)
z_bin_bounds = np.linspace(0.0, size_z, n_bins_z+1, dtype=np.float64)

# ----- np.digitize to get 'bin index' for each particle in each dim
# --> this basically creates 3 new scalars which are integer-valued 'flags'
#      for the sorting process later

bin_inds_x = np.digitize(data[:,0], x_bin_bounds)-1
bin_inds_y = np.digitize(data[:,1], y_bin_bounds)-1
bin_inds_z = np.digitize(data[:,2], z_bin_bounds)-1

# ----- re-organize total list into a 3D array of sub-arrays

data_resorted = np.empty(shape=(n_bins_x, n_bins_y, n_bins_z), dtype=object)

inds_all = np.array(range(n_pts), dtype=np.int32)

# ----- method 1

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
counter=1; particle_counter=0
for i in range(n_bins_x):
    for j in range(n_bins_y):
        for k in range(n_bins_z):
            #print('%i/%i'%(counter,n_bins_total)); counter+=1
            a = np.where(bin_inds_x==i) ## if in the current searched-for x-bin
            b = np.where(bin_inds_y==j) ## if in the current searched-for y-bin
            c = np.where(bin_inds_z==k) ## if in the current searched-for z-bin
            d = np.intersect1d(a, b) ## if in x AND y bin being searched for
            e = np.intersect1d(c, d) ## if in x AND y AND z bin being searched for
            inds = inds_all[e] ## take the particles meeting those criteria
            count = len(inds)
            if (count > 0):
                particle_counter += count
                data_resorted[i,j,k] = data[inds,:] ## assign matched points to 're-organized' array

end_time = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print('method 1 time: %0.2f[s]'%end_time)

if (particle_counter == n_pts):
    print('all pts binned %i %i'%(particle_counter, n_pts))
else:
    print('pts lost! %i %i'%(particle_counter, n_pts))

# ----- method 2

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
counter=1; particle_counter=0
for i in range(n_bins_x):
    inds = np.copy(inds_all)
    inds = inds[np.where(bin_inds_x[inds]==i)] ## index 'mask' for this x-bin
    inds_copy_i = np.copy(inds) ## matches in (x)... copy for re-use in nested (y,z) searches
    for j in range(n_bins_y):                  
        inds = np.copy(inds_copy_i)
        inds = inds[np.where(bin_inds_y[inds]==j)] ## index 'mask' for this y-bin
        inds_copy_j = np.copy(inds) ## matches in (x,y)... copy for re-use in nested (z) searches
        for k in range(n_bins_z):
            #print('%i/%i'%(counter,n_bins_total)); counter+=1
            inds = np.copy(inds_copy_j)
            inds = inds[np.where(bin_inds_z[inds]==k)] ## index 'mask' for this z-bin
            count = len(inds)
            if (count > 0):
                particle_counter += count
                data_resorted[i,j,k] = data[inds,:] ## assign matched points to 're-organized' array
end_time = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print('method 2 time: %0.2f[s]'%end_time)

if (particle_counter == n_pts):
    print('all pts binned %i %i'%(particle_counter, n_pts))
else:
    print('pts lost! %i %i'%(particle_counter, n_pts))
```

The output is:

```
method 1 time: 1.79[s]
all pts binned 100000 100000
method 2 time: 0.04[s]
all pts binned 100000 100000
```

'method 2' shows a big performance advantage over 'method 1', but I still get the feeling that I am not utilizing numpy correctly for this task, which might be able to be performed in a more 'vectorized' way within numpy, or using another numpy function.

Is there a better, more efficient way to 'bin' particles in 3D in python/numpy?

Comment: Your two solutions produce the same results. Are they what you expect? -did you validate the result (`data_resorted`)? `data` has six *items* in the second dimension yet you are only digitizing the first three - is that what you intended?

Comment: @wwii yes, i want to 'bin' based on the first three attributes, which are the x/y/z spatial coordinates (the first three columns of 'data')

Comment: np.histogramdd ... I have used it to bin 2D points.  No clue whether it is faster or not ... np.histogramdd(XY, bins=[(0, 10, 20, 30, 40), (0, 10, 20, 30, 40)]) where the bins represent the x and y bin edges.  You can add a Z bin.  Worth a look

Comment: For me at least it wold be nice if there were comments in the code explaining why/what - for instance in the first solution what are the series of `np.where` and `np.intersect1d` statements doing? - again, did you validate that your solutions do what you intended?

Comment: @wwii yes it does what i want/expect. i've added some comments to try to clarify the process. the big advantage in method 2 is that the successively reduced 'index mask' gets copied for re-use at every nested level, so there's less effort to search for matches at the inner (y,z) levels. for example, once i know which particles match in (x,y), i can iterate in (z) over this reduced list. method 1 does a full 'search' over all points in the original list for every (x,y,z) combination.

Comment: @NaN that was one thing I originally looked at, but as far as i can tell, `np.histogramdd` just counts the samples in each bin (or computes their density)... it doesn't really 're-organize' the original data in a lossless way, which is what i'm trying to do.

Comment: After you digitize do you need to actually put the vectors in something or can you just associate the *bin coordinate* with each vector?